# Stacked Master Detail using Interactive Grid in Oracle APEX 19.2

Tags: oracle-apex, master-detail, oracle-apex-19.1

I've created a page with stacked master detail based on two different tables.
I used default configuration
table2 -> master region: #region with master#
table2.id_from_table_1 -> master detail > master column > table1.id

I want to have possiblity to save master and detail independently of each other.

First problem is when I'm adding a record to master without saving I can add a row to detail (how to disable it? how to disable add to detail before master is submited?) and it result with an error that is caused of table2.id_from_table_1 that contains someting like 't1000'.

The second problem is when I added a record to master and save it succesfully and then without touching master i want to add a row to detail it doesn't use the id from the master, and again it causes the error with table2.id_from_table_1.

Both problems error:

> ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error

Next situation
I have added something to detail, without filling the required value and I'm returning to masted and I want to add/edit something in master and I can't save only master it still showing the error from detail and forcing me to fix the errors in detail. I need to have master and detail submit independently.

Comment: Paweł Żurkiewicz, are you still having issues with this? If so, could you put an example on apex.oracle.com and provide developer credentials to the workspace?